# How to create a new dataset with aggregated values by month in r?

Tags: r

My data set "data1" somewhat looks like this

```
Price       class
243            1
32             2
45             3
245            1
67             2
343            3
567            1
.
.
```

and so on, in class column 1,2,3 repeats itself continuously till the end of data (298 observations).

I want to aggregate it, such that I get the mean of each class. The data should look like. The data should be on a new dataset "classdata"

```
class          column_name
1        mean of all class 1 prices
2        mean of all class 2 prices
3        mean of all class 3 prices
```

I tried this code

```
classdata = aggregate(x=data1$Price, by=list(data1$class),  FUN="mean")
```

But I am not getting the desired result. Please help.

Comment: `aggregate(Price~class, data1, mean)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want proper column names. To get them also put `x=` into a list, and name the lists in both arguments.

```
aggregate(x=list(column_name=data1$Price), by=list(class=data1$class),  FUN="mean")
#   class column_name
# 1     1    351.6667
# 2     2     49.5000
# 3     3    194.0000
```

---

*Data:*

```
data1 <- structure(list(Price = c(243L, 32L, 45L, 245L, 67L, 343L, 567L
), class = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Another option is to use the `tidyverse` data processing model:

```
# use the data jay.sf made
data1 <- structure(list(Price = c(243L, 32L, 45L, 245L, 67L, 343L, 567L), 
                        class = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L)), 
                   class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))


library(tidyverse)

data1 %>% # start with sample data and pipe it to the next line
  group_by(class) %>%  # group the data by class and pipe it to the next line
  summarise(`The Mean Price` = mean(Price))  # Make a variable called "The 
                                             # Mean Price" holding the mean of 
                                             # the price variable.
```